# Include TFS changeset number with publish

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a TFS2015 build definition, which builds the source of a web application, and publishes it to a web site.

I would like to extend my build definition to create and copy a small text file, containing the TFS changeset number of the source which was built, to the *bin* folder of the target web site.

(I need this, because when browsing the web site, I would like to be able to see which specific version of the application I'm using)

Thanks.

Comment: You should set the version of the web application dll file with the build number (you can use the build task from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks). Then in your web application you can display the assembly's version using FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo method.

Comment: Yes, this could be a nice solution, but I am not sure I can have this custom build task installed in our TFS unfortunately, so I'm still looking for alternative solutions

Comment: Instead of a custom build task you can use a PowerShell script.

Comment: The revision number in .NET assembly version numbers cannot be greater than 65534, so I cannot use the assembly version numbers to store this information, because we may have a higher changeset number in TFS in the future.

Comment: Are you using vNext build or XAML build?

Answer (score 0):

Task `Version Assemblies` versions assemblies to match the version portion of the build number, not changeset. If you accept to use build number instead of changeset, this task will be a good option.

Otherwise, you need to add a PowerShell task customize your own script to get source version and create your small test file.